# Where can I modify global ignore.conf in macOS?

Tags: plasticscm

I've added a file extension to the ignore.conf but I marked the "Apply rule for all workspaces" and that adds it to another ignore.conf file that's not in my repository.

I'm on macOS and I can't find where that global ignore is. Googling found it for Windows but not for macOS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't have a "plastic-global-config" repo so the client configuration in a macOS should be found in the following paths:

/Users/xxx/.plastic4/ignore.conf

or

/Applications/PlasticSCM.app/Contents/MonoBundle/ignore.conf

Comment: Thanks to you I found it in the `.plastic4/` folder :)